# React Native limitations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, reactjs, react-native

I don't know a lot about mobile development, but the possibility of writing native mobile apps in JS interests me a lot.

However, correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont think that React Native is about to replace traditional native code anytime soon. Why is this the case? What are the limitations of React Native, that prevents it from replacing traditional native development?

Any insight is much appreciated

Comment: Some javascript programmers think that all programming should be done in javascript even if it's one of the worst programming languages to mantain. No, React Native won't replace anything. It will only help web developers to implement simple native applications. Emphasis on simple.

Comment: Why is it the react native only lends itself to simple native applications?

Answer (score 15):

At Facebook we're excited about RN for a few reasons:

1. Development velocity - refreshing is much faster than compiling, especially for big complicated apps
2. Separation of concerns - Experts on each platform can build high-quality native infrastructure and product developers can focus on their apps
3. Easier education - Developers can learn ES6+React once, and then build apps for iOS, Android, and of course the web

We used React Native to build the Facebook Ads Manager app for iOS, which is a pretty complicated app. It is working for us, but it probably won't work for everyone. This is a new technology that you should use at your own risk. Although we are working hard, it is not perfectly stable yet

Comment: Could you elaborate on why RN may not work for some people/projects? What are its shortcomings

Comment: You say "Android" but from what I see it supports iOS only...

Comment: React Native for Android isn't production-ready yet, and we don't want to open source it until it is. Plus it is very tightly integrated with other Fb technologies right now. We've got a group of great engineers working on making it happen within the next few months

Comment: @SergeyAldoukhov It already supports Android and iOS and it seems, in close future, we will be able to create apps for OSX and PCs with same technology stack. https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-desktop (right now there is only initial release supporting OS X)